# Start a process on linux startup

Tags: linux, unix, boot

I need to start a process when our linux/unix boxes (These boxes are used as build agents) are starting (ie: after a reboot). We use the following distros:

1. debian 6
2. ubuntu 12.something
3. FreeBSD
4. CentOS 6
5. Suse 12.something :)

Can you please let me know what should I make in order for this to happen?

Thank you,
f.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221757/run-automatically-program-on-startup-under-linux-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to put your command in /etc/rc.d/rc.local. The rc.local script is run after all the other System V init script are done.

Answer (score 0):

In general the same process should work for all those distro's but you might have to tweak them to suit their specific implementation.

Have a look at "run levels", determine at which level you want to start your scripts (usually 3 for a server and 3 & 5 for a graphical client) and then follow this:

http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/install-boot-login/428743-how-run-script-startup.html

In a nutshell, you create your startup script (best copy and modify an existing one - for the sake of example call it "myScript") and place it in /etc/init.d. Then in /etc/init.d/rcX.d (where X is your run level) place links to the script you put in /etc/init.d.  The links should be named SxxmyScript and KxxmyScript.  The "S" links get followed on startup - i.e. when the system *enters* that runlevel, and the "K" links get executed when the system exits that runlevel.

More recent distributions use *services* which are a more elegant twist on the above, but the above should work.

Also, for completeness look at /etc/inittab.  This isnt available on all distributions (i.e. ubuntu) but should be present on SuSE.  This is a proper old throwback but is still very much used these days in older environments.